# RTF editor cannot resolve symbol "editor"

Tags: java, android, editor, rtf

I am beginner in programming on Android. I would like to check, how this library works. I want to check one of the possibilities in my own project, but there is a problem - I do not know how to declare variable "editor" and also "preview"

**MainActivity code:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RichEditor mEditor;
private TextView mPreview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mEditor = (RichEditor) findViewById(R.id.editor);
    mEditor.setEditorHeight(100);
    mEditor.setEditorFontSize(12);
    mEditor.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
    mEditor.setPlaceholder("Insert text here...");

    mPreview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.preview);

    mEditor.setOnTextChangeListener(new RichEditor.OnTextChangeListener() {
        @Override public void onTextChange(String text) {
            mPreview.setText(text);
        }
    });
    RichEditor editor = (RichEditor) findViewById(R.id.editor);

    editor.setOnTextChangeListener(new RichEditor.OnTextChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChange(String text) {
            // Do Something
            Log.d("RichEditor", "Preview " + text);
        }
    });
    findViewById(R.id.action_bold).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override public void onClick(View v) {
            mEditor.setBold();
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Well you declared mEditor and mPreview and even assigned them an instance. What is the problem?

Comment: `mEditor = (RichEditor) findViewById(R.id.editor);` and `editor = (RichEditor) findViewById(R.id.editor);`. Why you need two pointers?

Comment: A problem is that Android cannot resolve symbol "editor". I am not sure if i declared it properly.

Comment: I dont know what should i add on activity_main that editor will be declare good

Comment: I have used this library https://github.com/wasabeef/richeditor-android and I am not sure how to implement it good.

Comment: `A problem is that Android cannot resolve symbol "editor".`. For which statement does this happen? Your code looks ok. 'If it works for mEditor all should work for editor too'. You should have said this!

Comment: I repeat: For what do you need two pointers?